# How to create scrollable table?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to create table which should be scrollable using php which i am able to achieve
when i give row even and odd color it became non scrollable  what should i do for this that when I add even and odd class name it should not  became non scrollable

Here is my code

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.wrap {
    width: 320px;

}

.wrap table {
    width: 300px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

table.head tr td {
    background: #eee;
}

.inner_table {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}</style
</head>
<?php
include('conn.php');
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM mesagerecord';


$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <table class="head">
        <tr>
            <td>Message</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
     <div class="inner_table">
    <table>

<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    if($i%2==0)
$classname="evenRow";
else
$classname="oddRow";
?>
       <tr>
            <td class="<?php echo $classname;?>"><?php  echo $row['message']; ?></td>

    </tr>
  <?php
$i++;}
?>
 </table>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php 
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

If I remove even odd class name it works fine.

Comment: </style close it </style>

Comment: please check, the answer have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use tbody and give the overflow will be auto and display to be block.

Can you check it?

Example:

Css

```
    <style>
    tbody {
        height: 100px;
        overflow: auto;
        display:block;
    }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Test Cases</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Test 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test 4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>  
    </table>
```